# Expected exit code 0, not 1?

Tags: c, cs50, edx

I submitted this problem set, but I'm unable to get a full mark grade because the exit code "is expected to be 0 and not a 1". However, if you take a look at the code (the recover.c file), the exit code is 0. What is wrong? The program accomplishes everything it was made for, which is to read through bits in a corrupted file and find the bits that make up a JPG file and write them in a separate file. The only problem I'm having is this aforementioned exit code issue. Please help!

recover.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "bmp.h"


int main (void){



    FILE* card_ptr = fopen("card.raw","r");

    if (card_ptr == NULL){

        fprintf(stderr,"File Not Found!");
        return 1;
    }

    BYTE buffer[512];

    bool found_jpg = false;

    FILE* new_jpg_ptr;

    int file_counter = 0;

    while(fread(buffer,1,512,card_ptr)!=0x00){

        if(buffer[0]== 0xff && buffer[1]== 0xd8 && buffer[2]==0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0)== 0xe0){

            if(!found_jpg){

                char filename[8];

                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", file_counter++);

                found_jpg = true;

                new_jpg_ptr = fopen(filename,"w");

                if(new_jpg_ptr == NULL){
                    return 2;
                }

                fwrite(buffer,1,512,new_jpg_ptr);

            }

            else {

                fclose(new_jpg_ptr);

                char filename[8];

                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", file_counter++);

                found_jpg = true;

                new_jpg_ptr = fopen(filename,"w");

                if(new_jpg_ptr == NULL){
                    return 3;
                }

                fwrite(buffer,1,512, new_jpg_ptr);


            }

        }

        else {

            if(found_jpg){

                 fwrite(buffer,1,512, new_jpg_ptr);

            }


        }




    }

    fclose(new_jpg_ptr);

    fclose(card_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

bmp.h file

```
/**
 * BMP-related data types based on Microsoft's own.
 */

#include <stdint.h>

/**
 * Common Data Types 
 *
 * The data types in this section are essentially aliases for C/C++ 
 * primitive data types.
 *
 * Adapted from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230309.aspx.
 * See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h for more on stdint.h.
 */
typedef uint8_t  BYTE;
typedef uint32_t DWORD;
typedef int32_t  LONG;
typedef uint16_t WORD;

/**
 * BITMAPFILEHEADER
 *
 * The BITMAPFILEHEADER structure contains information about the type, size,
 * and layout of a file that contains a DIB [device-independent bitmap].
 *
 * Adapted from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183374(v=vs.85).aspx.
 */
typedef struct 
{ 
    WORD bfType; 
    DWORD bfSize; 
    WORD bfReserved1; 
    WORD bfReserved2; 
    DWORD bfOffBits; 
} __attribute__((__packed__)) 
BITMAPFILEHEADER; 

/**
 * BITMAPINFOHEADER
 *
 * The BITMAPINFOHEADER structure contains information about the 
 * dimensions and color format of a DIB [device-independent bitmap].
 *
 * Adapted from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx.
 */
typedef struct
{
    DWORD biSize; 
    LONG biWidth; 
    LONG biHeight; 
    WORD biPlanes; 
    WORD biBitCount; 
    DWORD biCompression; 
    DWORD biSizeImage; 
    LONG biXPelsPerMeter; 
    LONG biYPelsPerMeter; 
    DWORD biClrUsed; 
    DWORD biClrImportant; 
} __attribute__((__packed__))
BITMAPINFOHEADER; 

/**
 * RGBTRIPLE
 *
 * This structure describes a color consisting of relative intensities of
 * red, green, and blue.
 *
 * Adapted from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162939(v=vs.85).aspx.
 */
typedef struct
{
    BYTE rgbtBlue;
    BYTE rgbtGreen;
    BYTE rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

Comment: Perhaps fopen failed, leading to the exit code 1 ?

Comment: Also this program overflows a buffer if there are more than 1000 input files

Comment: `fclose(new_jpg_ptr);` is called always, but sometimes `new_jpg_ptr` is uninitialized

Comment: @M.M When I run the code it actually works. Only when I submit it for grading, does the grading bot find a problem.

Comment: @user8468882 perhaps the grading bot fails to open a file called "card.raw"

Comment: It would help if you posted the exact problem stipulation and conditions

Comment: There's an awful lot of blank lines in the tail of that code.  It makes it hard to read -- too much white space is as bad as too little white space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced the same problem. My program worked as expected with no obvious reasons for a return code of `1`. As you have, I had also included a header file with some definitions in it. Placing those definitions in the core file solved my problem. Perhaps if you move the needed definitions from your `bmp.h` file into `recover.c`, `check50` will be able to compile.

My solution if you're interested.

```
// Recover any forgotten JPEGS from a given forensic image

# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdbool.h>
# include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

typedef struct
{
    BYTE byte_1;
    BYTE byte_2;
    BYTE byte_3;
    BYTE byte_4_min;
    BYTE byte_4_max;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
SIG;

// declare helper function prototypes
int check_args(int argc, char *argv[]);
bool signature_is_present(BYTE potential_sig[4], SIG jpeg_sig);

SIG set_jpeg_signature(void);

// main program
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // check input for validity
    int check_args_value = check_args(argc, argv);
    if (check_args_value != 0)
    {
        return check_args_value;
    }

    // call function to set default jpeg signature
    SIG jpeg_sig = set_jpeg_signature();

    // open buffers and declare other necessary variables for later use
    BYTE FAT_block[512];
    BYTE first_byte[1];
    int signature_offset = -4;
    int counter = 0;

    // open forensic image
    FILE * inptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE * outptr = NULL;

    // loop through file searching for first '255'
    while (fread(first_byte, sizeof(BYTE), 1, inptr) == 1)
    {
        // check if byte is 255, the first byte of a jpeg signature
        if (*first_byte == jpeg_sig.byte_1)
        {
            // check for signature
            BYTE possible_sig[4];

            // back pointer up one byte to compensate for already discovered 255
            fseek(inptr, -1, SEEK_CUR);

            // read four bytes from file that could potentially be a signature.
            fread(possible_sig, sizeof(possible_sig), 1, inptr);

            if (signature_is_present(possible_sig, jpeg_sig))
            {
                // close previously open write file, if any.
                if (outptr != NULL)
                {
                    fclose(outptr);

                    //Increment counter for image signatures found.
                    counter++;
                }

                // setup name for image file
                char file_name[8] = {};
                snprintf(file_name, 8, "%.3i.jpg\n", counter);

                // move pointer back 4 bytes after checking what they contain
                fseek(inptr, signature_offset, SEEK_CUR);

                //read FAT block from forensic image into buffer
                fread(FAT_block, sizeof(FAT_block), 1, inptr);

                // open new output file based on current signature
                outptr = fopen(file_name, "w");

                // write FAT block buffer to file
                fwrite(FAT_block, sizeof(FAT_block), 1, outptr);
            }
            else // byte is 255 but not part of a signature
            {
                if (outptr != NULL)
                {
                    // move pointer back 4 bytes after checking what they contain
                    fseek(inptr, signature_offset, SEEK_CUR);

                    //read FAT block from forensic image into buffer
                    fread(FAT_block, sizeof(FAT_block), 1, inptr);

                    // write FAT block buffer to file
                    fwrite(FAT_block, sizeof(FAT_block), 1, outptr);
                }
            }
        }
        else // if byte is not 255
        {
            if (outptr != NULL)
            {
                //back up one byte
                fseek(inptr, -1, SEEK_CUR);

                //read FAT block from forensic image into buffer
                fread(FAT_block, sizeof(FAT_block), 1, inptr);

                // write FAT block buffer to file
                fwrite(FAT_block, sizeof(FAT_block), 1, outptr);
            }
        }
    }

    // close files
    fclose(inptr);

    if (outptr != NULL)
    {
        fclose(outptr);
    }

    return 0;
}

// helper functions
int check_args(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid Input.\nForensic image file must be provided.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *inptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "File does not exist.\n");
        return 2;
    }

    fclose(inptr);

    return 0;
}

bool signature_is_present(BYTE potential_sig[4], SIG jpeg_sig)
{
    if( potential_sig[0] == jpeg_sig.byte_1 &&
        potential_sig[1] == jpeg_sig.byte_2 &&
        potential_sig[2] == jpeg_sig.byte_3 &&
        potential_sig[3] >= jpeg_sig.byte_4_min &&
        potential_sig[3] <= jpeg_sig.byte_4_max )
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

SIG set_jpeg_signature(void)
{
    SIG jpeg_sig;

    jpeg_sig.byte_1 = 255;
    jpeg_sig.byte_2 = 216;
    jpeg_sig.byte_3 = 255;
    jpeg_sig.byte_4_min = 224;
    jpeg_sig.byte_4_max = 239;

    return jpeg_sig;
}
```